# How can I set a password for single user mode?

Tags: linux, hardening

During a Lynis audit I found this on a system that uses Fedora 28:

Checking Linux single user mode authentication    WARNING

[image]

And under results I got:

```
        No password set for single mode [AUTH-9308]
```

[image]

Rkhunter skips "Checking for hidden processes"
[image]

What more can I do to harden this system? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To password-protect single user mode, you need to replace the single user mode shell with something like `sulogin`.  [Here's a page that describes how to do it](https://sites.google.com/site/syscookbook/rhel/rhel-single-user-require-root-password) under the various major RHEL variants, which should cover your Fedora variant.

I'm assuming based on recentness of Fedora 28 that it looks somewhat like RHEL 7, in which case you'll want to check the ExecStart line of /usr/lib/systemd/system/rescue.service.  The link above suggests it should look like this:

```
ExecStart=-/bin/sh -c "/usr/sbin/sulogin; /usr/bin/systemctl --fail --no-block default"
```

If you don't see `sulogin` in that line, that's your problem.

Please note that in most cases requiring a boot time password is meaningless unless you're also performing disk encryption, and that disk encryption should have a separate prompt for its password before you even get to this point.  So this setting may be redundant, depending on your system configuration, which is the sort of nuance an audit tool might miss.

As for the rkhunter issue, do you have `unhide` installed?  [This link](https://easy-admin.ca/index.php/2017/03/31/the-unhide-command-used-by-rkhunter/) suggests that if it is missing, that would explain why hidden process checking is skipped.

Comment: After I installed unhide, the hidden process check was not skipped and it turned out well.